# Reset formatting of code to default

Tags: netbeans, format

I am using NetBeans for my C++ development.

Previously there was nice formatting of code but it has changed.

This is the format that I want
[image: this is the format that i want]

This is the format that I am getting
[image: and this is the format that I am getting look at braces]

Note the two closing braces in one line after connection line and also the closing braces after semicolon in else statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you press crtl + a then right click, you will find a "format" option. I hope this helped!

Comment: I can also format it with ctrl+alt+F but my question is that my default formatting has been changes how do I change it...